# ¿Cómo puedo alinear a la derecha la celda de total en dinero? ItextSharp asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itextsharp

Tengo el siguiente documento pdf: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que necesito alinear las celdas de dineros a la derecha, para efectos de suma.

El código de esa parte es el siguiente:

```
PdfPCell Total_dinero = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total En Dinero", _standardFont));                
            Total_dinero.BorderWidth = 0;
            Total_dinero.BorderWidthBottom = 0.75f;
            Total_dinero.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(52, 209, 176);
            pdfTableCaja.AddCell(Total_dinero);

/*SEGUNDA FILA*/
            pdfTableCaja.AddCell('$'+ddvalor1.Text);
            pdfTableCaja.AddCell(serieInicio1200.Text);
            pdfTableCaja.AddCell(serieFin1200.Text);                
            pdfTableCaja.AddCell(boletosCortados1200.Text);
            pdfTableCaja.AddCell(total1200.Text);
```

Entonces, cómo hago para alinear a la derecha la celda de total en dinero?

Comment: Puedes probar `Total_dinero.HorizontalAlignment =  Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;`

Comment: hice ese cambio, pero solo me alinea y titulo "Total En Dinero" a la derecha

Comment: Tal ven puedas encontrar tu respuesta en [ItextSharp horizontal alignment in a pdfptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889857/itextsharp-horizontal-alignment-in-a-pdfptable).

Comment: es la misma solución que me habías dado jajaja

Comment: Tienes que hacer lo mismo **para cada celda que quieras alinear**

Comment: y cómo hago eso?

Comment: no, justamente ahí tienes VARIAS respuestas y te explica lo que te trata de decir @SJuan76

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias @FranIslas